# Cannot run simple Extjs code

Tags: extjs

This one will be most probably easy question. I'm very new to Web programming and I was given a task to learn Ext JS (I don't know anything about it they just told me to learn this, may be there are some better frameworks out there, but I don't know). So I started with a very simple example.
This is the Ext JS code

```
Ext.define('Cookbook.Vehicle', {
    config: {
        Manufacturer: 'Aston Martin',
        Model: 'Vanquish'
    },

    constructor: function(config) {
        // initialise config object
        this.initConfig(config);
    },

    getDetails: function() {
        alert('I am an ' + this.getManufacturer() + ' ' + this.getModel());
    },
});

var myVehicle = Ext.create('Cookbook.Vehicle');
myVehicle.getDetails(); // alerts 'I am an Aston Martin Vanquish'
```

And this is the HTML Code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="extjs/resources/css/extall.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Chapter 1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h2 id="h2">Nothing seem to work</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

I suppose that Ext JS code should run after the .hmtl file is launched right? But the thing is, nothing happens. Just a plane page which says Nothing seems to work. Is there a problem in my code? Or is there a special thing to be done to run Ext JS code. I don't really know what to do.

Comment: Did you check in Firebug if your "Chapter 1.js" file is actually loaded into the page and its content is the code you've posted?

Comment: Yeah. the code is loaded perfectly. If I change Chapter 1.js content to just something like alert('some_value'); it works perfectly but the code I posted above seems to have problem to run, and I don't know what is causing it.

Comment: I tested your case on my machine and it works - alert is shown. Any errors in your console? Maybe ext-all-debug.js isn't loaded? By the way, there is no 'extall.css' file but 'ext-all.css' is. But I'd be surprised if that's the cause of the problem.

Comment: this day is full of surprises mate :D you were right. I changed link's href attribute to all-ext.css and now it's working perfectly. Thanks mate.

Comment: ext-all.css not all-ext.css